# Could not call an object without any arguments in it

Tags: java

I know that a similar question has been answered before in other questions but all the ones i found does not apply to my situation so i decided that i ask it.

**This line gives an error:**

```
User users = new User();
```

**Error message:**

```
constructor User in class User cannot be applied to given types;
  required: String,String,String,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

**Below is my java class file.**

```java
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String pwd;
    private String email;
    private String role;

    public User(String username, String pwd, String email, String role) {
        this.username = username;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPwd() {
        return pwd;
    }

    public void setPwd(String pwd) {
        this.pwd = pwd;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have one constructor that takes 4 `String`s and try to call a constructor that takes nothing, which doesn't exists, so the compiler says "nope". Notice that a default constructor will only be defined for you when you haven't defined any constructor yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` constructor takes 4 arguments: `username`, `pwd`, `email`, and `role`, and you're trying to construct it with `new User()`, which provides none of the arguments. You should actually provide them:

```java
User user = new User("username here", "pwd here", "email here", "role here");
```

Or, create a constructor with no arguments of the form:

```java
public User() {
    this.username = /* some default value */;
    this.pwd = /* some default value */;
    this.email = /* some default value */;
    this.role = /* some default value */;
}
```

Or, to reuse your constructor:

```java
public User() {
    this(/* username default */, /* pwd default */, /* email default */, /* role default */);
}
```

You could use `null` as the default value, but that will probably just lead to `NullPointerException`s down the line.

Comment: If i create a constructor with 
```
public User() {
}
```
will it still be able to use getter and setters?

Comment: Yes, it'd be a `User` like any other constructor with access to all of `User`'s methods. However, the values that you get may be `null` if you don't initialize them.

Comment: yeah, the issue im facing now is that i keep getting null on all my values, i setUsername on another interface then when i getUsername in another interface, it returns null

Comment: Which is why you should provide default values like my answer told you to instead of just leaving it up to the compiler.

Comment: sorry... i keep getting null even if i have default value, how do i initialize them?

Comment: Either, provide default values like my answer told you to, or make sure you call a setter before you call a getter.

Comment: may we move to chat? sorry for taking  up ur time but i would like to show u my code and hope that u can help me >.<

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225127/discussion-between-etcasual-and-aplet123).

Answer (score 1):

Just create another constructor:

```
public User(){}
```

When you make a class this constructor is made for you by default. When you create a constructor yourself, this default constructor isn't made for you anymore and you have to add it in yourself.